# Remove flags in PhpStorm

Tags: configuration, phpstorm

How to remove the gray "column" flag (and others) in the PhpStorm configuration?

Example:

[image]

Please if I have to improve the title of the question, let me know.

Comment: @Lazyone, yes, it's duplicate. Should I delete the post?

Comment: and thank you very much!

Comment: It's up to you.